# catch exception from class file to aspx.vb page

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

This function is in a Class file in `App_Code` folder

```
 Public Shared Function CRUD(ByVal _sql As String, ByVal _parameterNames() As String, ByVal _parameterVals() As String) As Integer
        Dim _noOfRowsAffected As Integer
        Dim _connection As SqlConnection = Global.Connection.GetDbConnection()
        Dim _command As New SqlCommand(_sql, _connection)

        Try
            If _parameterNames IsNot Nothing Then
                For i = 0 To _parameterNames.Length - 1
                    _command.Parameters.AddWithValue(_parameterNames(i), _parameterVals(i))
                Next
            End If

            _noOfRowsAffected = _command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'MsgBox(ex.Message)
            _noOfRowsAffected = -1
        Finally
            If _connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                _connection.Close()
                _connection.Dispose()
                _command.Dispose()
            End If
        End Try

        Return _noOfRowsAffected
    End Function
```

This code is in aspx.vb page

```
Protected Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
        Dim _parameterNames(6), _parameterVals(6) As String
        _parameterNames(0) = "@Name"
        _parameterVals(0) = txtCoachingName.Text
        _parameterNames(1) = "@Address"
        _parameterVals(1) = txtCoachingAddress.Text
        _parameterNames(2) = "@Mob1"
        _parameterVals(2) = txtCoachingMob1.Text
        _parameterNames(3) = "@Mob2"
        _parameterVals(3) = txtCoachingMob2.Text
        _parameterNames(4) = "@LLine"
        _parameterVals(4) = txtCoachingLLine.Text
        _parameterNames(5) = "@Established"
        _parameterVals(5) = ddlCoachingEstablished.SelectedValue
        _parameterNames(6) = "@DemoVideo"
        _parameterVals(6) = txtCoachingDemoVideo.Text
        _parameterNames(7) = "@Password"
        _parameterVals(7) = txtCoachingPassword.Text
         Try
        DataAccess.CRUD("UPDATE CoachingDetails SET Name=@Name,Address=@Address,Mob1=@Mob1,Mob2=@Mob2,L_Line=@LLine,Established=@Established,Demo_Video=@DemoVideo,Password=@Password,Step_Completed='True',Time_Stamp='" & Date.Now & "'", _parameterNames, _parameterVals)
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Now i want to catch the `Primary Key Violation` exception in my `aspx.vb` page..but i do not get the exception in the `aspx.vb` page as the error is caught by the class function.So, how do i get the exception from the class file to the aspx.vb file??
        End Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rethrow](http://www.selfelected.com/rethrow/). (http://www.selfelected.com/rethrow/)

```
Try
    ....
Catch ex As Exception 
    do some stuff with ex
    Throw    ' important to not use ex as parameter as that would start a new exception stack.
Finally
    do some other stuff
End Try
```

Since you don't do anything in the catch just skip it.

```
Try
    ....
Finally
    do some other stuff
End Try
```

To make the code nicer read up on [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx).  With Using you can have the compiler insert the Try/Finally implicitly for you.  The code will be something like:

```
Using connection As SqlConnection = Global.Connection.GetDbConnection()
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        If parameterNames IsNot Nothing Then
            For i = 0 To parameterNames.Length - 1
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterNames(i), parameterVals(i))
            Next
        End If
        noOfRowsAffected = _command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Please note that I made all your variables local.  This might not be possible for you since you know a lot more about your code than I do...  (but the code suggested that your variables where class variables but you treated them as local anyway.)

Also check out [Dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/).  Dapper is what Stack overflow runs on.  It is a nice small lib for making writing sql calls easier to write and read.

Comment: Just one more doubt..if i am rethrowing the exception...that means i will have to have a try catch block in the aspx.vb page also??so whats the point of having two try catch blocks (one in class file and one in aspx.vb file)...rather i would have only one try catch block in my aspx.vb file?? i might be wrong..kindly explain.

Comment: Updated my answer with example on avoiding Catch but keeping Finally and using Using instead and finally a plug for Dapper.  HTH

Answer (score 1):

The BCL does not have a `PrimaryKeyViolationException` that can be caught.

The closest thing is to catch a `SqlException` and look at the message to see what the issue SQL Server reported is. The `Catch` block for this should be *above* the catch block for `Exception` as it is more specific.

```
Try
    If _parameterNames IsNot Nothing Then
        For i = 0 To _parameterNames.Length - 1
            _command.Parameters.AddWithValue(_parameterNames(i), _parameterVals(i))
        Next
    End If

    _noOfRowsAffected = _command.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch ex As SqlException
    ' Do stuff - logging, checking the exception message etc...
    ' Rethrow exception if you want the exception to bubble up
Catch ex As Exception
    'MsgBox(ex.Message)
    _noOfRowsAffected = -1
Finally
    If _connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        _connection.Close()
        _connection.Dispose()
        _command.Dispose()
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: how do i get the exception from the aspx.vb file??? if i have a try catch block in the class file it catches the exception..so if i use a try catch block in the aspx.vb file...it does not catch any exception.

Comment: i want to access the exception thrown in the class file from the aspx.vb file.

Comment: @user1150440 - Yes. In that case, you need to rethrow the exception from you catch blocks, so it will bubble up to the calling code. This is what I put in the code comment and in my first comment to you.

Comment: Isnt that a bad practice to re throw the exception??

Comment: does rethrowing an exception has any downside??

Comment: @user1150440 - Well, if you want to catch it in the calling code, you don't really have a choice. And rethrowing has the downside that you now have to handle the exception in the calling code (which may or may not be what should happen).

Comment: Just one more doubt..if i am rethrowing the exception...that means i will have to have a try catch block in the aspx.vb page also??so whats the point of having two try catch blocks (one in class file and one in aspx.vb file)...rather i would have only one try catch block in my aspx.vb file?? i might be wrong..kindly explain.

Comment: @user1150440 - Well, yes, that's the point of rethrowing. If you don't catch it in the calling code (or globally somewhere), the application will crash. What's the point? It depends on the application if there is a point or not.